# Updating attribute not working properly Meteor / MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to update a document by clicking a button. However, I keep getting an "Internal error" message. The document I am trying to update is called "confirmed" and it can take true/false values.

**Here's my `methods.js`:**

```
Meteor.methods({

'confirmUser1': function(currUserId) {
    var currentUserId = currUserId;
    Meteor.users.update(currentUserId, {$set:
        {
            'confirmed': true
        }
    });
    console.log('user verified!');
}
});
```

**Here's my template events helper:**

```
Template.Users.events({
'click .confirmUser': function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentUserId = this._id;

    Meteor.call('confirmUser1', currentUserId, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            alert(error.reason);
        } else {
            console.log('success!');
            Router.go('Admin');
        }
    });
}
});
```

**My button:**

```
<p><button class="confirmUser">Confirm User</button></p>
```

***Note:*** I used code very similar to this for a different update button/method and it worked fine... so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: and did you have that confirmed field on the users document? or you have `profile.confirmed`? if you run `Meteor.user()` also what error is throwing the console?

Comment: No, i do not have a confirmed field yet. I tried adding a confirmed field, but it still wouldn't work. Furthermore, I don't want the confirmed field to be part of profile. I want it to be at the same level as the profile attribute...

Comment: I don't get any error if i run Meteor.user(). The console just returns my user object and its associated attributes.

Comment: Do something very quickly, did you have a username? try to update te existing username field just change `'confirmed': true` to `username:"testa"`, just to see that happened, the method/call looks ok, so the internal error should be complaining about that confirmed field that doesn't exist. (maybe idk)

Comment: that's also giving me an internal server error...

Comment: change `var currentUserId = this._id;` to `var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();` try printing the `currentUserId` and see if you get the user `_id`

Comment: Still is not working... Surprisingly though, I tried that on another update and the method worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `Meteor.userId();`, the context of this inside an event handler is quite different as using inside a `Template.helper`

If you do a `console.log(currentUserId)` you should get undefined.

So change this

```
var currentUserId = this._id;
```

to this.

```
var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
```